# How to pass array variable from controller to view (Laravel 5)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My array ($response_array) is like this :

```
Array
(
    [Auth] => Array
        (
            [UserID] => test
            [UserIP] => 123
            [XmlVersion] => Testing Version
        )

    [SearchAvailRequest] => Array
        (
            [CountryCd] => ID
            [CityCd] => JOG
            [CheckIn] => 2016-01-08
            [CheckOut] => 2016-01-09
        )

    [SearchAvailResponse] => Array
        (
            [Hotel] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [HotelNo] => 1
                            [HotelCode] => 321
                            [HotelName] => Test 1 Hotel
                            [RmGrade] => Deluxe
                            [RmGradeCode] => DLX
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [HotelNo] => 2
                            [HotelCode] => 212
                            [HotelName] => Test 2 & 1 Hotel
                            [RmGrade] => Deluxe
                            [RmGradeCode] => DLX
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I want to send the hotel data to view

So the view display data like this :

```
Hotel Name
Check In
Check Out
City
```

I try like this :

Controller :

```
  ...
   return view('frontend.hotel.main_list_hotel',[
  'hotel' => $response_array['SearchAvailResponse']['Hotel']
]);
    ...
```

View :

```
 @foreach($hotel as $key=>$value)
{{ $key }}
{{ $value['HotelNo'] }}                     
@endforeach
```

I get hotel no & hotel name

How to get check in, check out, city and country?

Any suggestions on how I can solve this problem?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `SearchAvailRequest` array, in the same manner that you did the `SearchAvailResponse` array:

```
 ...
   return view('frontend.hotel.main_list_hotel',[
  'hotel' => $response_array['SearchAvailResponse']['Hotel'], 
  'city_info' => $response_array['SearchAvailRequest']
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
return view('frontend.hotel.main_list_hotel', [
    'availability' => [
        'checkIn' => $response_array['SearchAvailRequest']['CheckIn'],
        'checkOut' => $response_array['SearchAvailRequest']['CheckOut'],
        'city' => $response_array['SearchAvailRequest']['CityCd'],
        'country' => $response_array['SearchAvailRequest']['CountryCd'],
        'hotels' => $response_array['SearchAvailResponse']['Hotel'],
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Or simpler: `'request' => $response_array['SearchAvailRequest']` and access the `request` items in the view when needed `$request['CheckIn']`

Answer (score 1):

Why not try the `with()` Laravel method ?

```
return view('frontend.hotel.main_list_hotel')->with(compact(response_array['SearchAvailResponse']['Hotel']));
```

All datas are sending to view and you can use :

`{{ $response_array['SearchAvailResponse']['Hotel'] }}`

In your blade template.

Comment: The `with` method is the same as the second parameter of `view()`